# Sum of Sigmoid of Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing, logistic-regression, log-likelihood

I have: $$p_{\text{sigmoid}_i} =\frac{e^{a+b{x_i}}}{1+e^{a+b{x_i}}}$$ where $x_1, \ldots, x_n$'s are generated from a normal distirbution with mean $\mu_0$ and $x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{2n}$ are generated from $\mu_1$. The $\sigma$ for both samples is the same. ($a$ and $b$ are some known parameters.)

Using $p$, I create $n$ Bernoulli experiments with $p = p_\text{sigmoid}$.

After getting the results of Bernoulli, by using Neyman-Pearson test, I need to discriminate 
$$\mathcal{H_0} = \Pr(m = m_0\mid y=1)$$ and $$\mathcal{H_1} = \Pr(m = m_1 \mid y=1)$$
between the samples created from the Bernoulli which originally created from $\mu_1$ and $\mu_0$

**My question is what is the sum of sigmoid of normal distribution? (with mean and variance as it's parameters so I can use it in log-likelihood ration)**

Comment: Where you wrote $m=m_0$, did you mean $\mu=\mu_0$?

Comment: Yes @MichaelHardy, sorry.

Comment: Usually a notation like $H_0, H_1$ would refer to two _hypotheses_, not to two probabilities. One thing I'm wondering is whether you have some prior probabilities of $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$, i.e. not conditional on the event $y=1.$ Another is what the number $n$ has to do with the problem. One could, for example, choose $\mu$ at random from $\{\mu_0,\mu_1\}$ with equal probabilities, then generate $x\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2),$ and then generate $y\in\{0,1\}$ with the probability depending on $x$ in the way described, and finally ask for $\Pr(\mu=\mu_0\mid y=1).$ And the number $n$ is then not there.

Comment: $\ldots\,$so when $n$ is there, then how does the meaning of the question change?

Comment: I agree the question is not so clear. Your point about null hypothesis and alternative is correct. And also the mean0 and mean1 are not random. They are predefined parameters and we create n samples from normal distribution from each of the means. The whole point of the question is using the log-likelihood in hypothesis testing which requires sum of pdf which in our case is sum of sigmoid of x. For samples I can reference to sum of Bernoulli which is bio nominal, but I don't know what is the sum of our multi step distribution and keeping the relation of means to the generated y's.

Comment: .. As in log-likelihood you need to sum probability of each sample, parameter n is the number of samples and it will play a role. (And maybe in more advanced case, X0 (generated from mean0) and X1 has different number of samples